# iOS)AudioUnitを用いてマイク入力にLPFをかける方法について

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

AudioUnitを用いてマイク入力信号を色々編集するプログラムを書こうとしたのですが、一向に上手く行かないので質問させていただきます。

やりたいこと
　マイク入力信号→LPF→コールバック関数（ AUNode は二つになるのでしょうか？）

確認済なこと
　マイク入力信号→コールバック関数( AUNode は変数名 inNode １つです)

環境
　iOS 7.1.1

バグ
　以下のソースの直後のAuGraphStart(mAuGraph)でプログラムが落ちる。
　エラーすら出ないときと、OSStatusのエラーコード10863が得られるときがある。

質問内容
　上記バグを修正するにはどのように変更したら良いのでしょうか

ソース

```
OSStatus status;

NewAUGraph(&mAuGraph);
AUGraphOpen(mAuGraph);

AUNode inNode;
//AudioUnit inUnit;
AudioComponentDescription acd;
acd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
acd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
acd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
acd.componentFlags = testAcd.componentFlagsMask = 0;
AUGraphAddNode(mAuGraph, &acd, &inNode);
AUGraphNodeInfo(mAuGraph, inNode, NULL, &_inUnit);

//LPF設定
AUNode lpfNode;
//AudioUnit lpfUnit;
acd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
acd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter;
AUGraphAddNode(mAuGraph, &acd, &lpfNode);
AUGraphNodeInfo(mAuGraph, lpfNode, NULL, &_lpfUnit);
AudioUnitSetParameter(_lpfUnit,
                      kLowPassParam_CutoffFrequency,
                      kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                      0,
                      300,
                      0),



//マイク入出力設定
UInt32 flag = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty(_inUnit,
                     kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                     1,
                     &flag,
                     sizeof(UInt32));
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_inUnit,
                              kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, 
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                              kOutputBus,
                              &flag,
                              sizeof(flag));

AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
audioFormat.mSampleRate       = 22050;
audioFormat.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
AudioUnitSetProperty(_inUnit,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                     1,
                     &audioFormat,
                     sizeof(audioFormat));

//接続
AUGraphConnectNodeInput(mAuGraph, inNode, 1, lpfNode, 0);

//コールバック設定
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
callbackStruct.inputProc = callbackfunc;
callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_lpfUnit,
                             kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              kInputBus,
                              &callbackStruct,
                              sizeof(callbackStruct));

flag = 0;

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_lpfUnit,
                              kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                              kInputBus,
                              &flag,
                              sizeof(flag));

status = AudioUnitInitialize(_inUnit);
status = AudioUnitInitialize(_lpfUnit);
AUGraphInitialize(mAuGraph);
CAShow(mAuGraph);
```

以上、ご教授ください。

Comment: このソースはひとつの関数内にすべて書かれているのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。上記コードは自作の初期化関数内に記述されているものです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS8 ですが以下のコードで動作確認しました。

ポイントは

- マイク > エフェクト > スピーカ の流れではコールバック関数は必要ない
- `kAudioUnitType_Effect` に設定できるオーディオのフォーマットは `float` でなければいけない（環境依存？）
- `AudioGraph` を使用する場合は `AudioUnitInitialize` の関数で `AudioUnit` の初期化は必要ない。今回のコードには含まれていなですが破棄等も同様に必要なし。

---

```
@interface MicInput ()
{
    AUGraph _processingGraph;

    AUNode    _ioNode;
    AudioUnit _ioUnit;
    AUNode    _filterNode;
    AudioUnit _filterUnit;
}

@end

@implementation MicInput

- (void)start
{
    OSStatus status;

    status = NewAUGraph(&self->_processingGraph);
    NSAssert(status == noErr, @"NewAUGraph fail : %@", @(status));
    status = AUGraphOpen(self->_processingGraph);
    NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphOpen fail : %@", @(status));

    {// AUNode の登録
        {// io
            AudioComponentDescription cd;
            cd.componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Output;
            cd.componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
            cd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
            cd.componentFlags        = 0;
            cd.componentFlagsMask    = 0;

            status = AUGraphAddNode(self->_processingGraph, &cd, &self->_ioNode);
            NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphAddNode fail : %@", @(status));
        }
        {// filter
            AudioComponentDescription cd;
            cd.componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
            cd.componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter;
            cd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
            cd.componentFlags        = 0;
            cd.componentFlagsMask    = 0;

            status = AUGraphAddNode(self->_processingGraph, &cd, &self->_filterNode);
            NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphAddNode fail : %@", @(status));
        }
    }

    {// AudioUnit の取得
        // io
        status = AUGraphNodeInfo(self->_processingGraph, self->_ioNode, NULL, &self->_ioUnit);
        NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphNodeInfo fail : %@", @(status));
        // filter

        status = AUGraphNodeInfo(self->_processingGraph, self->_filterNode, NULL, &self->_filterUnit);
        NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphNodeInfo fail : %@", @(status));
    }

    {// processingGraph 内のフォーマットを統一する

        AudioStreamBasicDescription description;
        description.mSampleRate       = 44100;
        description.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        description.mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
        description.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
        description.mBytesPerPacket   = sizeof(Float32);
        description.mBytesPerFrame    = sizeof(Float32);
        description.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
        description.mBitsPerChannel   = 8 * sizeof(Float32);
        description.mReserved         = 0;

        // mic out
        status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self->_ioUnit,
                                      kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                      kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                      1,
                                      &description,
                                      sizeof(description));
        NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty fail : %@", @(status));

        // filter in
        status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self->_filterUnit,
                                      kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                      kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                      0,
                                      &description,
                                      sizeof(description));
        NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty fail : %@", @(status));

        // filter out
        status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self->_filterUnit,
                                      kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                      kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                      0,
                                      &description,
                                      sizeof(description));
        NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty fail : %@", @(status));

        // speaker in
        status = AudioUnitSetProperty(self->_ioUnit,
                                      kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                      kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                      0,
                                      &description,
                                      sizeof(description));
        NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty fail : %@", @(status));
    }

    {// マイク入力を有効化
        UInt32 flag = 1;
        AudioUnitSetProperty(self->_ioUnit,
                             kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                             kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                             1,
                             &flag,
                             sizeof(UInt32));
        NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty fail : %@", @(status));
    }

    {// filter の設定
        AudioUnitSetParameter(self->_filterUnit,
                              kLowPassParam_CutoffFrequency,
                              kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                              0,
                              300,
                              0);
        NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AudioUnitSetProperty fail : %@", @(status));
    }

    // ioNode(mic out) -> filterNode -> ioNode(speaker in)
    status = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(self->_processingGraph,
                                     self->_ioNode, 1,
                                     self->_filterNode, 0);
    NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphConnectNodeInput fail : %@", @(status));

    status = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(self->_processingGraph,
                                     self->_filterNode, 0,
                                     self->_ioNode, 0);
    NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphConnectNodeInput fail : %@", @(status));

    status = AUGraphInitialize(self->_processingGraph);
    NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphInitialize fail : %@", @(status));

    AUGraphStart(self->_processingGraph);
    NSAssert(status == noErr, @"AUGraphStart fail : %@", @(status));
}

@end
```

Comment: iOS7でも無事動作することを確認しました。丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。